# Show hide JS div css

Tags: javascript, css

im familiar with php, but a serious learner in js, i have tried 3 methods to achieve my goal and i have seen the method used below that seems the easiest to implement so i can achieve my goal, but for some reason it does not work. I have included only the necessary bits for the specific function that isnt working, this all works inside a while loop based on entries in a db, seperated with a {$page_trackid} to distinguish between each function and link to it.

I understand a 'this' style function could be used, but as i say im so new to js im just trying to achieve the necessary before i extend to getting even more complex.

Is there something im doing totally wrong here?

Cheers

```
<head>

    <style>
        .hidden {display:none;}
        .visible {display:block;}

        .subtext_img {
            width: 100px; height: 100px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; float: right;
        }

        .subtext {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        .arrow_box { padding-left: 100px; position: absolute; z-index: 100; background: #88b7d5; border: 4px solid #c2e1f5; width: 580px; height: 120px;} .arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before { left: 100%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; } .arrow_box:after { border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0); border-left-color: #88b7d5; border-width: 10px; top: 30%; margin-top: -10px; } .arrow_box:before { border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0); border-left-color: #c2e1f5; border-width: 16px; top: 30%; margin-top: -16px; }


    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <?
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_Uploaded_Tracks WHERE username = '$user' ORDER BY datetime DESC")
            or die(mysql_error());

    $page_trackid = '1'; //reset page track id
    // get a whole bunch of data, track info & user info based on some cross referencing via id
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {

        $db_trackid = $info['id'];
        $username = $info['username'];

        //data 2 track info based on db track id
        $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_Uploaded_Tracks WHERE id = '$db_trackid' LIMIT 1")
                or die(mysql_error());

        $info2 = mysql_fetch_array($data2);


        //data 3 is user profile data based on db track id
        $data3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1")
                or die(mysql_error());

        $info3 = mysql_fetch_array($data3);

        //data 4 profile image based on user id, track uploader*
        $data4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_profile_pic WHERE username = '$username' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1")
                or die(mysql_error());

        $info4 = mysql_fetch_array($data4);

        echo "
        <script>
            function showbox(userinfo_{$page_trackid}){
                document.getElementById(userinfo_{$page_trackid}).style.visibility='visible';
            }

            function hidestuff(userinfo_{$page_trackid}){
                document.getElementById(userinfo_{$page_trackid}).style.visibility='hidden';
            }
        </script>
        <div id='userinfo_{$page_trackid}'  class='arrow_box' style='display: none;'>  <img src='" . $info4['Image'] . "' class='subtext_img'>
            <h2 class='subtext'><a href='http://XXXX/XXX/" . $info2['username'] . "'>" . $info2['username'] . "</a></h2>
            <p class='subtext'>" . $info3['user_title'] . "</p>
            <p class='subtext'><a href='" . $info3['website_link'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $info3['website_link'] . "</a>

            </p>

        </div>";

        echo "
            <div style='position: absolute; z-index: 1; width: 20px; height: 20px; padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 699px;'>
                <a href='javascript:showbox_{$page_trackid}()'><img style='height: 20px;' alt='Track stats' src='http://XXXXXX/play1/skin/user-profile2.png' style=''></a>
            </div>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Ugh! Bad indentation, skip question.

Comment: Have you considered using a join or two to fetch the data from the database?

Comment: "does not work" is not a suitable description. Please describe what you are trying to do and what actually happens, including an error messages. And since this is a client side javascript question, please post the HTML received at the client, not the PHP that generates it.

Answer (score 0):

[Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): avoid manipulating an element's style directly in javascript. styling belongs with css.

Here's what I would do:

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// show an element
document.getElementById("my-id").classList.remove("hidden");

// hide an element
document.getElementById("my-id").classList.add("hidden");
```

classList is not supported in old browsers, so make sure to include the polyfill at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList

Comment: Suggesting adding and removing a class is a good idea, but recommending a solution that does not work in a good number of browsers in use is not. The linked shim doesn't work in IE 8 and lower at least, and likely many other less common browsers in various devices. The alternative is a very simple add/remove class function that will work everywhere.

Comment: I'd like to too but this isn't the case. Though a comment stating the compatibility is OK for me ;)

Comment: @bart—yes, misread the compatibility statement. But there are many other browsers in the same boat as IE 7. Note that most browser stats don't tell you version numbers (other than IE usually) and some browser upgrades are tied to OS upgrades so old ones hang around a lot longer than you think, e.g. Safari support is missing in OS X 10.5 and lower.

Comment: @RobG I can't deny it's not 100% compatible, but these days, hardly anything is. It's a vicious circle: if you keep supporting old browsers, they'll never die out. If they never die, you feel the need to continue supporting them. I say: the market share of browsers without classList (or polyfill) support is insignificant.

Comment: "...it's not 100% compatible...hardly anything is". There are strategies for being compatible with pretty much every user agent in use, it isn't difficult. "if you keep supporting old browsers, they'll never die out" It's not your place as a developer to tell users what user agent they should be using on the web. And if it was, not supporting older browsers when there's a sound solution that does is not a good strategy for doing so.

Comment: @RobG The only reason users don't update IE (most other browsers auto-update these days) is because developers continue to support old browsers. I would also like to point out - again - that `classList` support is overwhelming. http://caniuse.com/classlist - I tested the polyfill on IE7 and contrary to what MDN says, the polyfill does work on IE7. http://caniuse.com/classlist - 95% support with polyfill.

Comment: @Bart—"The only reason users don't update IE…". What research to you have to backup that assertion? My experience is that there are many reasons, a primary one being that browser upgrades are often tied to OS upgrades and users (including corporations) don't want to upgrade their OS or change to another browser. Also, some devices come with a browser that can't be easily upgraded by a user. There are many other reasons too.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that in the HTML you are setting the *display* property to *none*, but in the script you are setting the visibility property. They are different things. Set one or the other in both places.